# Grep 6th column of a row in a file and replace it with string

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

I have a file having ddl's as below.. now 6th column in the line starting with (Create table if not exists tbl1) is table name.. i want to replace table name with DB.table name.
And in the line having location it should populate $tbl as table name. Below is sample input and output.

```
    Create table if not exists tbl1 (
    col1 int;
    col2 string )
location hdfs://directory/$tbl
    Create table if not exists tbl2 (
    col3 int;
    col2=4 float)
location hdfs://directory/$tbl
```

After replacing the output should become like below

```
    Create table if not exists DB.tbl1 (
    col1 int;
    col2 string )
location hdfs://directory/tbl1
    Create table if not exists DB.tbl2 (
    col3 int;
    col2=4 float)
location hdfs://directory/tbl2
```

Can anyone suggest how to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

`sed` - powerful linux command used for text substitutions.

`sed 's/tbl/DB.tbl/' filename` - will replace **all** occurences of 'tbl' with 'DB.tbl' and achieve the wanted result. (use it carefully).

Further reading: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sed-command-in-linux-unix-with-examples/

`awk` might also help:

`grep "Create" filename | awk '{print $6}'` - will print the 6th column of lines with the word "Create" in filename.

Good luck.